# Creating forms with multiple input types

Tags: django, html, python-3.5

I am trying to create an input form field which can take text, images or videos as we see in Twitter.

I am trying the following:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Tweet

class TweetModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(label='',
                widget=forms.Textarea(
                        attrs={'placeholder': "Your message",
                            "class": "form-control"}
                    ))
```

Which produces [image]

However, I am trying to use the same input box so that user can upload image, video, GIFs or just type text in the box. I am not sure how to modify the above form field.

Edit:
If it is not possible using Django, can this be done using HTML5?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you want to display the image when the user uploads it?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You should use a WYSIWYG Editor for that like [Froala Editor](https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor)

Usage

```
from django import forms
from froala_editor.widgets import FroalaEditor

 class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
     content = forms.CharField(widget=FroalaEditor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a WYSIWYG plugin? Django summernote might work
https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote

You could then set the widget to SummernoteWidget in the form

Answer (score 0):

For adding file upload in `Django` form you need to add `FileField` into your form class.

Update your **forms.py** as below.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Tweet

class TweetModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(label='',
                widget=forms.Textarea(
                        attrs={'placeholder': "Your message",
                            "class": "form-control"}
                    ))
    file = forms.FileField(label="Upload file", blank=True)
```

This would render separate file field that user could upload images and other files.

Comment: This method can upload the file but it doesn't create twitter kind of box where the image shows up in display immediately.